# IOS UI failing to update appropriately (Bug?)

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

Hi I think I have encountered a somewhat unique bug with my code. I believe it has to do with my iPhone storing some type of cached interface.

Here are some pictures highlighting the bug.

This first picture shows how I want my table cells to be displayed as and 
how they are displayed in the IOS Simulator

[image]

and here is how the table is displayed on my phone

[image]

as you can see through the images my phone has failed to display the same table view as the simulator.

The Xib file I am working with matches the simulator view.

Originally I had the xib designed like how it is on the phone but changed it a couple days ago and haven't gotten the view to be able to update correctly on the phone.

here is the code I am using to generate the table.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";

 TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
 {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:simpleTableIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
NSLog(@"Here are the book names, %@",_bookNameArray);
NSLog(@"here are the prices, %@", _priceOfBookArray);

cell.priceOfBookLabel.text = [_priceOfBookArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.bookNameLabel.text = [_bookNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.authorNameLabel.text = [_authorNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.bookImageLabel.file = _bookImageData[indexPath.row];
[cell.bookImageLabel loadInBackground];

    return cell;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing the problem?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You encountered a bug with your code! And where is the code?

Comment: I don't believe it is a bug with the code, I think it has to do the phone storing some type of cache of the interface

Comment: Could be either. Maybe he is adding some label programatically in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or maybe it's cache. Can't be sure without seeing the code. If its not doing that, just cmd+shift+k (clean) the project, delete the existing app from phone and run it again

Comment: added in the code i am using interface builder to create the TableViewCell i tried the cmd+k it had no effect

Comment: Well then clean the project and delete the app from phone. Reinstall it again. That ought to fix it if you are sure it's nothing wrong with the xib or code (code looks fine).

Comment: i tried the cmd+k plus a reinstall but had no luck

Comment: you might have your IBOutlets assigned incorrectly, or you have autolayouts enabled and you havnt put any autolayout constraints on your views which can make them land up in strange places

Comment: The thing is I don't even have the extra label outlet in the xib anymore it was deleted completely